# Scala 2.10.1 and specialization (can't get it working right)

Tags: performance, scala, generics, boxing, scala-2.10

Sorry for asking second time about specialization, but I haven't good understanding of what the heck is going on yet...
So, I have one project (Gomoku game with AI), and I decided to use my own simple and dirty @specialized ad-hoc collections in the hot part of it, because I must store primitive types without boxing. The problem is that this doesn't really help, because in `jvisualvm`'s Sampler I clearly see

```
scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.boxToShort()
```

eating up *thousands* of ms when the optimal move search starts running.

The project: https://github.com/magicgoose/Gomoku
The file with the poor "collections": https://github.com/magicgoose/Gomoku/blob/master/src/magicgoose/gomoku/ai/SpecializedCollections.scala
The method, which causes boxing (one of them, I think):

```
trait Indexed[@specialized T] extends Enumerable[T] {
  @inline def length: Int
  @inline def apply(i: Int): T
// ...
  @inline final def findIndex(fun: T => Boolean) = {
    @tailrec def find(i: Int): Int = {
      if (i < length) {
        if (fun(this(i))) i
        else find(i + 1)
      } else -1
    }
    find(0)
  }
}
```

I have seen another project (debox: https://github.com/non/debox), which tries to accomplish the similar thing (data collections without primitive boxing), but I don't really understand how it is done there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has an easy answer: `Function1` is not specialized on `Short` arguments, only `Int`, `Long`, `Float`, and `Double`.  So when you call `fun` you need to box on the way in.

Either use your own function class--sadly lacking the convenient shorthand!--or make sure you are not using `Short => Boolean` but rather `Int => Boolean` (and the types know it).  Note that when I said it was easy, I meant only easy to explain the problem: neither solution is all that easy to implement, but at the moment this is what's necessary.

Comment: Oops. This is so strange. Btw, I can get rid of Short and use Int everywhere and pack 2 Ints to Int instead of packing 2 Bytes to Short, this is dirty, but ok for this particular application, since the ranges of valuaes are anyway limited. Now I'll try it and see if there will be an improvement.

Comment: I have switched to Ints and now there is no boxing.